# Why I get error in python program with multiple loops?

Tags: python, loops

I am trying to make a program to work out how many apples are on the tree, some falling, some taken and some appearing.

The different stages are the four different trees, each trees can give apples to the other trees.  for example tree c will lose 0.12 (probability) of apples but gain 0.28 (probability) of apples for tree b.

**There is an error in my program, I just don't know where. I need the program to run for 20 runs but it only runs for 1.**

```
from __future__ import division
from pylab import*
n=input("please enter the number of runs: ")

a=50
b=40
c=60
d=80

#stage 1
i=0
while i<=n:
    a1=a-(a*0.24)
    b1=b-(b*0.29)-(b*0.28)+(d*0.09)
    c1=c-(c*0.12)+(b*0.28)
    d1=d-(d*0.09)+(d*0.24)+(b*0.29)+(c+0.12)
    i=i+1
    if a1<a:
        print "the population of apples in stage one after run ", n,
        print "has decreased to ", a1
    else:
        print "the population of apples in stage one after run ",n, 
        print " has increased to ", a1

#stage 2
    if b1<b:
        print "the population of apples in stage two after run ", n,
        print "has decreased to ", b1  
    else:
        print "the population of apples in stage two after run ", n, 
        print " has increased to ", b1
#stage 3
    if c1<c:
        print "the population of apples in stage three after run ", n,
        print "has decreased to ", c1
    else:
        print "the population of apples in stage three after run ",n, 
        print " has increased to ", c1
#stage 4
    if d1<d:
        print "the population of apples in stage four after run ", n,
        print "has decreased to", d1
    else:
        print "the population of apples in stage four after run ",n, 
        print " has increased to ", d1
        i=i+1
```

Comment: please fix the indention of your code. Also, why are you incrementing i twice in one iteration?

Comment: The position of while is a bit strange

Comment: This runs 44 times after I delete `from pylab import*`. You should really break this program down into functions and use more descriptive variable names.

Comment: Should also only have one of the `i=i+1` lines, but I had it working correctly as well by removing the `pylab` import.

Comment: Try `while i <= int(n)`, instead of `while i <= n`. It looks like you compare `i` to a string

Answer (score 1):

You need to start i at 1, then just increase after each run, you were using n not i to track each run.

```
from pylab import*
n=input("please enter the number of runs: ")

a=50
b=40
c=60
d=80

#stage 1
i=1
while i<=n:
    a1=a-(a*0.24)
    b1=b-(b*0.29)-(b*0.28)+(d*0.09)
    c1=c-(c*0.12)+(b*0.28)
    d1=d-(d*0.09)+(d*0.24)+(b*0.29)+(c+0.12)
    print i
    if a1<a:
        print "the population of apples in stage one after run ", i, # needs to be i not n
        print "has decreased to ", a1
    else:
        print "the population of apples in stage one after run ",i,
        print " has increased to ", a1

#stage 2
    if b1<b:
        print "the population of apples in stage two after run ", i,
        print "has decreased to ", b1
    else:
        print "the population of apples in stage two after run ", i,
        print " has increased to ", b1
#stage 3
    if c1<c:
        print "the population of apples in stage three after run ", i,
        print "has decreased to ", c1
    else:
        print "the population of apples in stage three after run ",i,
        print " has increased to ", c1
#stage 4
    if d1<d:
        print "the population of apples in stage four after run ", i,
        print "has decreased to", d1
    else:
        print "the population of apples in stage four after run ",i,
        print " has increased to ", d1
    i+=1
```

Answer (score 0):

You weren't printing the value of `i` on each loop. You were printing `n`.

I was only able to find your error by refactoring your code with the functions `runLog` and `appleLog`. Using good variable names and function modularization goes a long way both toward avoiding errors and saving you time and effort.

Also, I used `for` instead of `while` because it is more appropriate for your application. Using `n+1` captures the `i <= n` condition you are looking for. This automatically increments `i` until it reaches the value of `n`.

```
from __future__ import division

n = input("please enter the number of runs: ")

a=50
b=40
c=60
d=80

def runLog(stage, run):
    print "the population of apples in stage {} after run {}".format(stage, run)

def appleLog(original, modified, stage, run):
    if modified < original:
        runLog(stage, run)
        print "has decreased to ", modified
    else:
        runLog(stage, run) 
        print " has increased to ", modified

for i in range(n+1):
    a1=a-(a*0.24)
    b1=b-(b*0.29)-(b*0.28)+(d*0.09)
    c1=c-(c*0.12)+(b*0.28)
    d1=d-(d*0.09)+(d*0.24)+(b*0.29)+(c+0.12)
    #stage 1
    appleLog(a, a1, stage=1, run=i)
    #stage 2
    appleLog(b, b1, stage=2, run=i)
    #stage 3
    appleLog(c, c1, stage=3, run=i)
    #stage 4
    appleLog(d, d1, stage=4, run=i)
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes Padraic is correct, and I agree with Chris's point.  But I did not see were 'n' was explicitly converted to an 'int'.  With out converting 'n' to an 'int', it will fail at the while loop, with a "TypeError: unorderable types: int() <= str()".

```
n = input("please enter the number of runs: ")
n = int(n)
```